# Is there a way to obtain 'NaN' using only numbers?

Tags: postgresql

PostgreSQL can contains `NaN` (not a number) value in numeric and float columns and variables: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-FLOAT

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=1fdf20510b1b6a1416754599c60fc93f

Is there a way to obtain `NaN` different of inserting or updating directly to such value?

In this question I considered that all of these are the same:

```
insert into t (v) values ('NaN');
insert into t (v) values ('N'||'a'||'N');
insert into t (v) values (E'\116\101\116');
insert into t (v) values (chr(78)||chr(65)||chr(78));
update t set v='NaN';
```

I try things like:

```
insert into numeros (id, n1, n2) values (5, 1e306/1e-306, 1e306/1e-306); -- not representable
insert into numeros (id, n1, n2) values (6, 0/0, 1/0);  -- division by 0
```

Comment: Are you looking for `select 'NaN'::float`?

Comment: My English is not good enough. No. I want to know if is there some operation involving numeric values that it gives as result a 'NaN'.

Comment: I tried `cot(0)`, but it gave me gave me 'Infinity'

Comment: With `ln(0)` I obtain `ERROR:  cannot take logarithm of zero`. I can not imagine the reason for the different behavior

Answer (score 3, accepted):

divide infinity by infinity.

```
jasen=# select cot(0)/cot(0);
 ?column? 
----------
      NaN
```

Comment: I can't believe it. But it is true. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=972dbeeb0f6816b5aeaa74f3172a1150

Comment: Or use `'infinity'::float / 'infinity'::float`

Comment: Also `0 * 'infinity'::float` and `0 * cot(0)`

Comment: 'infinity' is not a number so I use `cot(0)` because `0` is a number.